# Flex in scrollable div wrong height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this flex container which does contain 2 columns. The contents of some of the columns is bigger then the conainers height thus the scrollbar is shown. This is ok.

However, when you scroll down the height of the background of the single columns is only as high as the containers heights and does not fill the entire height (below the top scroll position).

Is there a way to fix this so that the yellow and green background is down to the bottom of the columns?

Here is fiddle:

```
<div class="outer-container">
<div class="column-one">col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one</div>
<div class="column-two">col two</div>
</div>

.outer-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.column-one {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 80px;
  background: green;
}

.column-two {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ioma8/Lmo94q6q/4/

Answer (score 3):

Just add another *wrapper* around the *columns* and `display` it as `flex`:

```css
.outer-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  /*display: flex; not necessary*/
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.column-one {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  background: green;
}

.column-two {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="column-one">col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one col one</div>
    <div class="column-two">col two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Before, everything worked as expected, *flex-items* took the whole defined `height` of the *parent* element, which is what they do, by default. So any extra content won't make them *higher* than their *flex parent* and keep them equal in *height*. That's why you need to `overflow` the *parent*, not the *children*. This is the reason behind the additional *wrapper*.